# jQuery Multiple .slide() In Navigation Without Selectors

Tags: jquery

I'm making a responsive theme for someone. I have made the menu, but I have using jQuery .slide() to make the menu slide open. The problem is that when I toggle to slide open the menu, it also slides open all sub-menus within it.

I can add selectors to fix this problem. However, by adding selectors, this means the user may have to alter the jQuery if he/she should add more sub-menus. So I'm trying to keep it so that the user never has to touch the jQuery.

Are there any solutions to this problem?

**HTML**:

```
<div id="LinkList1">
    <div class="menu-toggle">Menu</div>
    <ul class="firstlevel">
        <li>First Link</li>
        <li class="share-toggle">First Link
            <ul class="secondlevel">
                <li>First Drop Link</li>
                <li>Second Drop Link</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
ul { display: none; }
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(".menu-toggle").click(function () {
    $("#LinkList1 ul").slideToggle("fast");
});
$(".share-toggle").click(function () {
    $("#LinkList1 ul ul").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/tXQzM/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle("fast");
});
$(".share-toggle").click(function (e) {
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle("fast");
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tXQzM/1/)**

You seem to be selecting all the `ul` in general irrespective of the depth of the  descendants.

So you would be using the `this` context that holds the currently selected element that generated the event and show the corresponding `ul` in it.